# Win32Exception on IIS while using Fsharp.Compiler.CodeDom

Tags: c#, iis, f#, codedom

I work on an web-api in F#/C# which runs on IIS.
In this application we compile F# scripts, that external users give us, at runtime using FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.

It works on a Windows service context, locally using IIS express but not on the Windows Server using IIS.

I think it is due to something between Fsharp.Compiler.CodeDom and the IIS context but so far I can't get to the bottom of this.

I have this exception : "***System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified.***"

The exception does not give me the source, neither which (damn) file it's talking about, I browsed around and tried some tricks :
- checking that the dependencies of F# are included in the assembly directory (bin folder).
- checking impersonation settings on IIS

So I came around to ask :
- Has something similar happened to someone before ?
- My understanding is that once the runtime is installed on the target and if the application contains F# Dll runtime, I do not need to install specific F# build tools on the server, am I right to think so ?
- Is Fsharp.Compiler.CodeDom sill the way to go to compile at runtime for F# ?
- Is there some special set up, if you want to use Fsharp.Compiler.CodeDom run on IIS ?

Comment: What's the stack trace in the exception?

Comment: @CurtNichols thanks for your time. In short it was due to the use of Fsharp.Data and the fact that since we compile for our users, we needed to add "DesignTime" Dlls so it works. Sorry for the late informations, for some reason, I thought that I replied to this thread month ago.